# Codec Issue while converting LocalDateTime to Cassandra TIMESTAMP

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have POJO attribute as below,

```
 @Column(name = "timeStamp")
 private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
```

This attribute coming from a service, and need to retain the format. I am streaming input from Kafka and need to store in Cassandra.

I'm creating table using datastax API,

```
CreateTable createTable = SchemaBuilder.createTable("sample31", "contactNew")
                    .ifNotExists()
                    .withColumn("timeStamp", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP);
```

When my job execution, am facing the below exception,

```
Codec not found for requested operation: [timestamp <-> java.time.LocalDateTime]
```

I tried with different data type such as `DataTypes.DURATION` ,  `DataTypes.DATE` not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Java driver 3.x you need to use a separate package - so-called "Optional codecs" by including an additional dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
  <version>driver-version</version>
</dependency>
```

For `LocalDateTime` from Java 8 there is a `LocalDateTimeCodec` ([doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#jdk-8)) that should be registered when you created a cluster object, like this:

```java
import com.datastax.driver.extras.codecs.jdk8.LocalDateTimeCodec;

cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry()
    .register(LocalDateTimeCodec.instance);
```

There is similar codecs for Java driver 4.x, starting with driver 4.8.  Also just register necessary codec as [described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/manual/core/custom_codecs/#mapping-cql-timestamps-to-local-date-time).  But the easiest way is to register all necessary codecs at the session build time with something like this:

```java
CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().addTypeCodecs()....build();
```

Comment: @alek i use ```CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()``` instance to execute my queries. Is there any way to register above?

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to Instant and it will be mapped automatically:

```
message.getLocalDateTime().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just register existing instance in latest dse java driver.

```
    import static com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.ExtraTypeCodecs.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP_UTC;

    MutableCodecRegistry registry = (MutableCodecRegistry) session.getContext().getCodecRegistry();
    registry.register(LOCAL_TIMESTAMP_UTC);
```